# How to prevent App Engine Build timeout while deploying to asia region

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Over the past few weeks my `gcloud app deploy` has been failing regularly, today it fails even after attempting 10 times so far. According to the google cloud web interface, it is failing after build in the exporting phase:

```
7: exporter
/cnb/lifecycle/exporter asia.gcr.io/<project>/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:<uuid>
```

Is there anything we can do about this at all?

(The build itself takes just a few minutes, then this `exporter` phase runs until the 10m mark and is killed.)

Perhaps there is a way to make `gcloud app deploy` do the build in the asia region?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy using App Engine Standard or Flexible? Could you post a minimum repro of your code and app.yaml files without sharing any PII or sensitive information?

Comment: It's appengine standard. `gcloud app deploy` apparently builds in a US region and then uploads the image into the asian region (which is the closest location to the actual appengine region).  My question is not regarding the duration it takes to build the code, but the duration it takes for the build to copy/transfer the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted everything in the Google Cloud Console under the "Container Registry" menu option. Not sure why that helps, but builds now average 2 minutes instead of the historical 9-11 minutes for the past year or so.

(Although this technically doesn't answer why behind the question, this does solve the strange delays in building on appengine (standard). I am going to mark it as solved and leave this question here in case others encounter the error message above.)